# For loop giving wrong probability arrays

Tags: python, loops, numpy

I'm trying to build a for loop that outputs arrays of probabilities in which the sum of each array equals to one.

I have the results of the 3 first arrays and are the following:

an initialized array of probabilities:

```
p = np.array([0.8, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

the two following arrays are found with this formula:

```
p[j+1] = p[j]*q[i] + p[j+1]*(1-q[i])
p[0] = p[0]*(1-q[i])
```

and they are:

```
np.array([0.64, 0.32, 0.04, 0, 0, 0])
np.array([0.6016, 0.3392, 0.0568, 0.0024, 0, 0])
```

The code I used is:

```
# q are the default probabilities that will help calculate the updated 
# p probabilities
q = np.array([0.8, 0.2, 0.2, 0.06, 0.3, 0.4])
p = np.array([0.8, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0])

x = np.array([2,3])
y = np.array([0,1])

for i, j in zip(x, y):
    p[j+1] = p[j]*q[i] + p[j+1]*(1-q[i])
    p[0] = p[0]*(1-q[i])
    print(p)
```

and as a result I get these two arrays:

```
[0.64 0.32 0.   0.   0.   0.  ]
[0.6016 0.32   0.0192 0.     0.     0.    ]
```

which differ from the results I showed earlier.

Comment: Where did `q` come from?

Comment: 'q' are the default probabilities that will help us calculate the updated 'p' probabilities.

Comment: The for loop iterates twice, first time (i, j) = (2, 0); second time (i, j) = (3, 1). Hence, first time through loop, since j == 0, only p[0] and p[1] can be set... p[2] is never assigned and hence cannot be set to 0.04. For the second time through the loop, since j == 1, only p[0] and p[2] can be set... p[1] retains it's value from the previous iteration and p[3] cannot be set at all. It seems that your loop logic is not what you intended.